# Myqli Query with condition

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I am using query for get json result. Its working fine but now I want only result fetched where qu_status=1 in table quotes. But I am not able to make it working. My working query without check above condition is like below

```
$sql = "SELECT q.*,c.au_picture as picture FROM tbl_quotes q INNER JOIN tbl_category c ON q.qu_author=c._auid Order By q.".$orde." Desc LIMIT ".$limit." OFFSET ".$offset;
```

I have tried to use it like below

```
$sql = "SELECT q.*,c.au_picture as picture FROM tbl_quotes where qu_status=1 q INNER JOIN tbl_category c ON q.qu_author=c._auid Order By q.".$orde." Desc LIMIT ".$limit." OFFSET ".$offset;
```

But I am wrong somewhere in this and so I can not getting any result. Let me know if someone can correct me. Thanks

Comment: the where clause should come after the inner join clause and before the order by clause

Comment: @Manav Thanks its working fine :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the where clause must be after the join so

```
$sql = "SELECT q.*,c.au_picture as picture 
      FROM tbl_quotes  q
      INNER JOIN tbl_category c ON q.qu_author=c._auid 
      where q.qu_status=1  
      Order By q.".$orde." Desc LIMIT ".$limit." OFFSET ".$offset;
```

or you can do directly in join avoiding where

```
$sql = "SELECT q.*,c.au_picture as picture 
       FROM tbl_quotes q
       INNER JOIN tbl_category c ON q.qu_author=c._auid and q.qu_status=1  

  Order By q.".$orde." Desc LIMIT ".$limit." OFFSET ".$offset;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to put the `where` condition behind the join.
Also prefix your condition with your defined alias `q`.

`...
where q.qu_status = 1
...`